# Need to Change Sale Badge Text in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The following works for the Product page but it does not work for the Shop page.

```
<?php
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'woocommerce_custom_sale_text', 10, 3);
function woocommerce_custom_sale_text($text, $post, $_product)
{
    return '<span class="onsale">PUT YOUR TEXT</span>';
}
```

Please suggest modifications.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Use This**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'wooc_custom_replace_sale_text' );
function wooc_custom_replace_sale_text( $html ) {
return str_replace( __( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ), __( 'Your Text', 'woocommerce' ), $html );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works perfectly for the shop page as well. You may try increasing the priority or it can be a conflict with some other plugin or theme.

You may also check the following file to confirm it has applied the woocommerce_sale_flash filter

```
woocommerce\templates\loop\sale-flash.php
```